# The command '/bin/sh -c cd X' returned a non-zero code: 2

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

I have an dockerfile for an node application which will have react build folder to run with with it.
My cd API command in Docker working.
My folder structure:

```
|-api (folder of node)
|-client (folder of react)
|-.dockerignore
|-.Dockerfile
```

```
FROM node:10

WORKDIR /app

RUN chgrp 0 ./ && \
    chmod g=u ./

ADD client /app/client
RUN cd api
COPY package.json /app

RUN npm install
RUN npm audit fix

COPY . /app

EXPOSE 9000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

What I want is to have client folder inside my container and then move inside api folder to copy package.json folder inside it and run rest commands.

Any idea for how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Each `RUN` command execute in separate shell, so that is why your current directory not preserved for next command.

```
RUN cd api
```

> What I want is to have client folder inside my container and then move
>   inside api folder to copy package.json folder inside it and run rest
>   commands.

your question is not so clear but I assume you want something like `copy package.json from API folder to client folder`, while you did not copy the `api` folder so it will not exist.

Try something like this

```
ADD client /app/client
COPY api/package.json /app/
```

as it this stage, `package.json` is inside `api` folder on host, not in the container.
or if you want to copy `package.json` from API to the client then try this

```
ADD client /app/client
COPY api/package.json /app/client
```

then you can execute rest of the command.

```
RUN npm install
RUN npm audit fix
```

correct me if this not what you are looking for.